# ajax not working to call asp.net web method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am calling asp.net web method in my ajax call. Web method looks like below

```
[WebMethod()]
public static int DropDownIndexChanged(string selectedText)
{
   int a = 5; // This is just to test
   return a;
}
```

And in my ajax call, i am sending selected value in a drop down, having id **DropDown**, as follows

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "FindFines.aspx/DropDownIndexChanged",
              data: { "selectedText":"+$("#DropDown option:selected").text()+"},
              success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
              }
});
```

But function is not being called. Please guide me the right way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you check the Firebug> What error is showing inside there?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `"+$("#DropDown option:selected").text()+"`

```
var value = $("#DropDown option:selected").text();
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "FindFines.aspx/DropDownIndexChanged",
              data: { "selectedText": value },
              success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
              }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Change

```
 [WebMethod()]
```

to

```
 [WebMethod]
```

and

```
 data: { "selectedText":"+$("#DropDown option:selected").text()+"}
```

to

```
  data: '{selectedText: "' + $("#DropDown option:selected").text() + '" }'
```